# Why Does The Size Of Binary File Does Not Decrease While Using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, .net

Why does the size Of a binary file not decrease while using `BinaryWriter`?
Consider this first piece of code:

```
static void write()
{
    BinaryWriter sr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("bin.txt"));
    int m;
    m = 123456;
    sr.Write(m);
    m = 122;
    sr.Write(m);
    sr.Close();
}
```

While using the above method the size of `bin.txt` is 8 bytes.

But when I remove `m = 122` and the second `Write` call from the function and run the program again, I expect the file size to be changed to 4 bytes, but it's still 8 bytes.

```
static void write()
{
    BinaryWriter sr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("bin.txt"));
    int m;
    m = 123456;
    sr.Write(m);
    sr.Close();
}
```

While Running Below Function By Adding double Type In It Than The Size    Of File Increases From 8 To 12 .

```
static void write()
{
    BinaryWriter sr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("bin.txt"));
    int m;
    m = 123456;
    sr.Write(m);
    double pp = 1233.00;
    sr.Write(pp);
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please don't capitalize each word in your text - it makes it *really* hard to read. And please look at the preview before you post, to make sure that only the code is formatted as code, and that it's nicely indented.

Comment: When you test properly (deleting the file before each run) the results will be what you expect.

Comment: @  Henk Holterman ,Yes I Have Tried Removing , Than It Work's Fine  . But I Want This To Work Without Deleting The File

Comment: Make sure you flush before close.  Sometimes data does get written immediately.

Comment: _I Want This To Work Without Deleting The File_ is OK but purely cosmetic. And your ShIfT KeY is still having problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `BinaryWriter`, really - it's the [`File.OpenWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite(v=vs.110).aspx) call, whose documentation includes:

> The `OpenWrite` method opens a file if one already exists for the file path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the OpenWrite method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").

So your second method does only write four bytes - but it overwrites the first four bytes of the file without truncating the file itself.

Use [`File.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, and any existing file will be truncated.

I'd also advise you to use `using` statements instead of closing resource manually:

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create("foo"))
{
    // Code here, no need to call writer.Close()
}
```